# cin input not being accepted in while loop

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to use a cin input but on my second while loop, the inputs are not running though correctly.  How would I go about this?

Here's what I have:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip> 
using std::endl; 
using std::cout; 
using std::cin; 
using namespace std;

int a, A;

int main() { 
    int choice, num; 
    
    cout << "State Search" << endl; 
    cout << "" << endl; 
    cout << "1. Enter the first letter of your desired state" << endl; 
    cout << "2. Press 2 to Quit" << endl; 
    cout << "" << endl;
    
    bool done = false;
    while(!done) {
        //user inputs desired choice
        cin >> choice;
        if(choice == a || choice == A)
        {
            cout << "Which State? (enter a number)" << endl;
            cout << "1. Alabama" << endl;
            cout << "2. Alaska" << endl;
            cout << "3. Arizona" << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            
            while (!(cin >> num)) 
            {
                if(num == 1) 
                {
                    cout << "test output 1" << endl;
                }
                
                else if (num == 2) 
                {
                    cout << "test output 2" << endl;
                }
                
                else if (num == 3) 
                {
                    cout << "test output 3" << endl;
                }
                
            } break;
        } break;
    } 
    return 0;

}
```

Once the user chooses one of the above states using a number I want to display the chosen output.

Comment: You program reads an int then compares it against two variables that will both be 0 because they are global and you never change them. Then the inner while loop will only be entered if input fails. You should take another look at your logic. `using std::endl;` and such are meaningless if you follow it up with `using namespace std;`.

Comment: Are you sure you want `while (!(cin >> num))` ?  What that says is "only enter the loop if reading a number failed."

Comment: Also you don't check that `cin >> choice;` succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a cleaned up version of what you are trying to do with some inline comment where you were going wrong.

```cpp
// You only need to include iostream in your example program
// Only include what you need
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

// You do not need to include all of the std namespace in the local scope
// if you are using the things you want.
using std::endl;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::streamsize;

int main()
{
        cout << "State Search\n\n";
        cout << "1. Enter the first letter of your desired state\n";
        cout << "2. Press 2 to Quit\n" << endl;


        // Removed all the while(!done) / break; as it is just noise in the current iteration of your program.

        // if you use an int for the choice variable, you will actually try to parse the input
        // as an integer and return 0 if the user inputs 'a'
        // you need to use a char for what you want to do
    
        char choice;
        cin >> choice;
        // Also your a and A int value do not make sense as they are init to 0 
        // (global initialization), I guess what you want to do is compare to the char 'a' or 'A'. You could also transform the input to lowercase and compare only to 'a'.
        if (choice == 'a' || choice == 'A')
        {
                // Use \n not std::endl as it will flush the output buffer
                // all the time. std::endl is a false friend, use it only
                // when you want to present your text to the user.
                cout << "Which State? (enter a number)\n";
                cout << "1. Alabama\n";
                cout << "2. Alaska\n";
                cout << "3. Arizona\n" << endl;

                // We want to wait until we get a correct input and _then_
                // do something with our input.
                int num;
                while (!(cin >> num))
                {
                   // You might want to say something to your user if he doesn't input a correct number here.
                   // This will succeed if the user inputs 4, so you might also want to handle that case differently and ask the user to retry too in that case.
                   // The stream is now in error, you need to reset the state of the stream by clearing the error and emptying the buffer.
                   cin.clear();
                   cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                }
                // Just showing another way of doing the if / else if dance in C/C++.
                switch(num)
                {
                        case 1: cout << "You chose Alabama" << endl; break;
                        case 2: cout << "You chose Alaska" << endl; break;
                        case 3: cout << "You chose Arizona" << endl; break;
                        default: cout << "I do not recognize the State" << endl; break;
                }
        }
        // if we didn't receive 'a' or 'A' we just quit the program.
        return 0;
}
```